# How to store data in a node in vis.js?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

Can you help me please ? I don't know how to put some data in a node in the vis.js library (Javascript)

The only properties I know are "id", "date", "label", "title", "image", "x", "y" but there is no property for storing datas (like user's username, age, etc. if my node represent an user)

At the moment, I store the data's in an input type="hidden" in the title property... But I don't know if there is a cleaner way to do it.

(Sorry if my english is not so good)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found how to do that. Simply add the property :

```
nodes.push({
    id:xxx,
    shape: xxx,
    image: xxx,
    label: xxx,
    title: xxx,
    property_1:xxx,
    property_2:xxx,
    property_3:xxx,
    ...,
    property_n:xxx
});
```